# rename strong parameters rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

i have an issue with mapping third-party response to my server

the response is

```
"id": ".....",
"external_id": "....",
"recurring_payment_id": "....",
"is_high": ...,
"payment_method": "...",
```

and i set my strong params like

```rb
def invoice_params
 params
  .require(:invoice)
  .permit({id: :invoice_id}, :external_id, :recurring_payment_id,
           :payment_method)
end
```

i want to rename id to invoice_id

but i got an error
`Unpermitted parameter: :id`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe strong parameter does not support what you did. You need to work around it by rename the params key.

There is an easier method using [alias](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveModel/AttributeMethods/ClassMethods/alias_attribute), but use with caution. Add this to your class.

```
alias_attribute :id, :invoice_id
```

Edit: swap order because `invoice_id` is attribute in db

Comment: i did but 
it can create the data but cant update it

Comment: somehow theres no error message but it didnt updated

Comment: `.permit(:id, :external_id, :recurring_payment_id,
           :payment_method)` @bren. Sorry for replying late

Answer (score 1):

```
    params[:id] = params.delete(:invoice_id)
    params.permit(:id)
```

or

```
    params[:invoice][:id] = params[:invoice].delete(:invoice_id)
    params.require(:invoice).permit(:id)
```